# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\cdots+\sqrt{k+1}}$?

Tags: limits

I am stuck on this one; Its a sum and don't know how to calculate the denominator.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\cdots+\sqrt{k+1}}$$

Comment: Did you at least checked it converges?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\cdots+\sqrt{k+1}}$?

Comment: the limit should be 0.
edit: exactly. sorry, I don't know how to use these characters, I'm on my phone.

Comment: The question would be more interesting with the prefactor $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ instead of $\frac1n$ (since then the limit would be $3$).

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to work out the following carefully, but at any rate, using comparisons with integrals, you should be easily able to see that the limit is zero. I could do it in my head.

We are considering
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\cdots+\sqrt{k+1}}.$$

First, note that 
$$\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{k} \approx \int_1^k s^{1/2} ds \approx \frac{2}{3} k^{3/2}.$$

Next, we then have approximately 
$$\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^{3/2}} \approx \frac{2}{3n}  \int_1^n \frac{1}{k^{1/2}} dk \approx \frac{4}{3n} n^{1/2}.$$

Clearly this goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Stolz-Cesaro lemma is applied twice successively:
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\cdots+\sqrt{k+1}} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+2-(n+1)} \frac{n+1}{1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\cdots+\sqrt{n+2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\cdots+\sqrt{n+2}}=\frac{n+2-(n+1)}{1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\cdots+\sqrt{n+3}-(1 + \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} +\cdots+\sqrt{n+2})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+3}}=0$$

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have a question:
on the second row, why is there 1/(n+2)-(n+1) and why is there n+1 instead of k which goes up to n?

Comment: @RandomHumanBeing: In the notation of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), $b_n$ = $n+1$, and $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{1+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{k+1}}$.